# URL Rewriting and redirection issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seedscrew\.org\.crew$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.seedscrew\.org\.crew$
RewriteRule ^crew/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/ "http\:\/\/www\.seedscrew\.org\crew\/index\.php\?mode=login&act=home" [R=301,L]
```

I have written in  in .htacess file. 
I want to redirect from hostpath/index.php?mode=login&act=home to hostpath/username

Comment: Clarify your problem with some examples.

Comment: I want to change url from "http://www.seedscrew.org/crew/?mode=login&act=home" to "http://www.seedscrew.org/crew/username". So I have done the aboove code for rewriting. but it is not working

Comment: In that case, aren't you missing a forward slash in front of `crew`?

Comment: I have added forward slash still not working.

Comment: http://www.seedscrew.org/crew/Webandcloud. Here "Webandcloud" is username

Comment: Please let me know if require more information to solve and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need this rule `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^crew/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /crew/?mode=login&act=home [QSA,L]
```

OR else this rule in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/crew/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /crew/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?mode=login&act=home [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I have written the same. Still its not working. Please help for the same.<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /crew/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?mode=login&act=home [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: What the actual URL did you try to test it and do you have other rules in `/crew/.htaccess` also?

Comment: From http://www.seedscrew.org/crew/?mode=login&act=home to seedscrew.org/crew/Webandcloud need to change. I do not have placed other rules

Comment: You need to enter `http://seedscrew.org/crew/Webandcloud` in your browser not the other URI

Comment: I have to rewrite all the site url, but this first one is not working. If it will be worked then I will do it for all. Here "webandcloud" is username. I need to change url this after login.

Comment: These all rules, I have applied, but removed it and and applied only rule given by you.
These all rules, I have applied, but removed it and and applied only rule given by you.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seedscrew\.org\.crew$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.seedscrew\.org\.crew$
RewriteRule ^crew/\$ "http\:\/\/www\.seedscrew\.org\crew\/index\.php" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seedscrew\.org\.crew$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.seedscrew\.org\.crew$
RewriteRule ^crew/\$1 "http\:\/\/www\.seedscrew\.org\crew\/index\.php/$1" [R=301,L]

Comment: Just answer simple question, what happens when you open `http://seedscrew.org/crew/Webandcloud`?

Comment: When I am checking with seedscrew.org/crew/webandcloud, I got error 404 not found and when I am using my code which is mentioned in the question, I got internal server error

Comment: Have you placed above .htaccess in `/crew/.htaccess`? Is mod_rewrite enabled? And is there any other rule in `/crew/.htaccess`?

Comment: Yes, I have placed .htaccess in crew folder and in starting of the code I have written <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>. Other rules are not done. I want to make it for http://www.seedscrew.org/crew/webandcloud only

Comment: Can you remove `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` line

Comment: Thanks Anubhava for the help. My issue is solved now.

Comment: There is this tick mark on top left of my answer. If you tick it it will turn green. This will give you some reps too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^crew/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ http://www.seedscrew.org/crew/index.php?mode=login&act=home [R=301,L] [R=301,L]
```

Remember [R=301,L] means you are redirecting request to specified url.
If it is in same context then use as follows. [crew is context here].

```
RewriteRule ^crew/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /crew/index.php?mode=login&act=home [L,PT]
```

Comment: The same url need to change, and still not working with the above code also.

Comment: When I am checking with http://www.seedscrew.org/crew/webandcloud, I got error 404 not found